# Converting JSON string to lisp(aml) readable string for evaluation using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, json

I'm trying to convert a JSON string to a stringformat that I can use to evaluate in Lisp (aml).

I want to convert f.eks.:

> {"id": 1, "name": "Foo", "price": 123, "tags": ["Bar","Eek"], "stock":
>     {"warehouse": 300,  "retail": 20} }

to:

```
(json-object (json-object-property "id" <1>) (json-object-property "name" <"Foo">) (json-object-property "price" <123>) (json-object-property "tags"(json-array (list "Bar" "Eek")) (json-object-property "stock"(json-object (json-object-property "warehouse" <300>) (json-object-property "retail" <20>)))))
```

I'm trying first to use C# and Regex to do it, and then "translate" it to lisp/aml. So my question is really:

How to do this using Regular expression in C#? I have tried a lot, but always ends up struggling with strings that inculdes not-word-characters, or to few "(".

I have never used regex before, so the code doesn't look very smart:

```
string input = @"{""id"": 1,""name"": ""Foo"",""price"": 123,""tags"": [""Bar"",""Eek""],""stock"": {""warehouse"": 300,""retail"": 20}}""";
string pattern = @"[}]";
string replacement = ")";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

pattern = @"((?<word1>""\w+"")(:\s)(?<word2>""\w+""|\d+))";
replacement = @"(json-object-property ${word1} <${word2}>)";
rgx = new Regex(pattern);
result = rgx.Replace(result, replacement);

pattern = @"[]]";
replacement = "))";
rgx = new Regex(pattern);
result = rgx.Replace(result, replacement);

pattern = @"[{]";
replacement = "(json-object ";
rgx = new Regex(pattern);
result = rgx.Replace(result, replacement);

pattern = @"[[]";
replacement = "(json-array (list ";
rgx = new Regex(pattern);
result = rgx.Replace(result, replacement);

pattern = @"[,]";
replacement = " ";
rgx = new Regex(pattern);
result = rgx.Replace(result, replacement);

pattern = @"(?<word1>""\w+"")(:\s)";
replacement = @"(json-object-property ${word1}";
rgx = new Regex(pattern);
result = rgx.Replace(result, replacement);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: If you really struggled with it, show us your code :)

Comment: see the code I added above